# mapping elements of an array differently based on position

Tags: ruby

I want to map elements of an array such that all elements
of the array are floats, except the first element which
is a string.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Tried this but doesn't work:

```
arr = arr.map { |e| e.to_i if e != arr.first }
```

Comment: Why not edit your question, and supply some sample data, and an example of the desired output too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is

```
[array.first] + array.drop(1).map &:to_f
```

This makes it clear that you want the first element separate from the rest, and you want the rest of the elements to be of type `Float`. Other options include

```
array.map { |element, index| index == 0 ? element : element.to_f }
array.map { |element| element == array.first ? element : element.to_f }
```

Comment: I think you meant: [array.first] + .... And this indeed the best solution, not checking inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a short ternary expression here:

```
a.map { |e| ( e == a.first ) ? e : e.to_f }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option (if you don't want to use ternary operators) is to do the following:

```
arr = arr.map { |e| (e == arr.first) && e || e.to_f}
```

This alternative is discussed [here](http://invisibleblocks.wordpress.com/2007/06/11/rubys-other-ternary-operator/). A limitation with this method is that the first element in the array cannot be nil (or some other value that would evaluate false in a boolean evaluation), because if so, it will evaluate to the `||` expression and return e.to_f instead of just e.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.9 only?

```
arr = arr.map.with_index { |e, i| i.zero? ? e.to_s : e.to_f }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the objects themselves whether they're numbers.

```
"column heading".respond_to?(:to_int) # => false
3.1415926.respond_to?(:to_int) # => true

new_arr = arr.map do |string_or_float|
  if string_or_float.respond_to?(:to_int)
    string_or_float.to_int # Change from a float into an integer
  else
    string_or_float # Leave the string as-is
  end
end
```

`respond_to?(:to_int)` means "Can I call `to_int` on you?"

`to_int` is a method that only objects that are readily convertable to integers should have. Unlike `to_i`, which is "I'm not very much like an integer, but you can try to convert me into a integer", `to_int` means "I'm very much like an integer - convert me into an integer with full confidence!"